# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'IConfiguration'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

i need to create a login with jwt . when i use this code :

```
        private string BuildToken(User user)
    {

        var claims = new[] {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.DisplayName),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Birthdate, user.BirthDate.ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
          _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
          claims,
          expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
          signingCredentials: creds);

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
```

it show me this error :

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0021  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'IConfiguration' StoreFinal  C:\Users\Mr-Programer\Desktop\New folder\StoreFinal\StoreFinal\Areas\Admin\Controllers\LoginController.cs   65  Active

show me in error in this line : `var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));`

Comment: Build a model to hold the desired data and bind that from the loaded `IConfiguration` at startup. Inject the model where it is needed.

Comment: @Nkosi's suggestion is the better approach here, but what you've shown should work. Is the `IConfiguration` type you're using here from a different namespace, for example?

Comment: @KirkLarkin is correct. There's nothing wrong with your code, assuming `IConfiguration` is `IConfiguration` from `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`. The only logical explanation for the error is that there's a different `IConfiguration` object somewhere in your codebase that is not a dictionary type.

Comment: I had this happen to me. 

I was using AutoMapper.Configuration

Instead of using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

Answer (score 9):

i add this using in namespace and it solved by this :

```
using IConfiguration = Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration;
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`